# Dynamically hiding children using ng-content in angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, components, parent-child, angular7

There is a scenario in my project where the content has to be hidden based on role permission given for a specific user logged in.

So we have made a global component named `<app-authorise>` where it will enable the children based on the permission that the user has.

**Component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { GlobalService } from '../../../core/global/global.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-authorise',
  templateUrl: './app-authorise.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-authorise.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default
})
export class AuthoriseComponent {
  @Input() public module: string;
  @Input() public permission: string;
  @Input() public field: string;
  @Input() public role: string;

  public currentUser: any = {};
  public currentUserRoles = [];
  constructor(private globalService: GlobalService) {
    this.globalService.subscribeToUserSource((updatedUser: any) => {
      this.currentUser = updatedUser;
      this.currentUserRoles = updatedUser.rolePermissions;
    });
  }

  get enable() {
    const {
      currentUser,
      currentUserRoles,
      module,
      permission,
      role
    } = this;
    if (currentUser && currentUserRoles) {
      return role ? this.hasRole(currentUserRoles, role) :
      this.globalService.hasPermissionForModule({
        currentUserRoles,
        module,
        permission,
      });
    }
    return false;
  }

  public hasRole(currentUserRoles: any, role: string) {
    return Boolean(currentUserRoles[role]);
  }
}
```

**Component.html**

```
<ng-container>
  <ng-content *ngIf="enable"></ng-content>
</ng-container>
```

**UseCase**

```
<app-authorise [module]="properties.modules.project" [permission]="properties.permissions.CREATE">
  <app-psm-list></app-psm-list>
</app-authorise>
```

The actual problem we are facing is the child component's **onInit()** method is getting called even when the child is enabled inside the parent component.

Any idea , advice on this will be highly helpfull.

Comment: Try to create Dynamic component instead of projecting Component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the condition before projecting `<app-psm-list>` component into `<app-authorise>`, so that `app-psm-list` components `ngOnInit()` won't be called if condition fails.

To do this you need some reference like `#authorise` against `app-authorise` component

```
<app-authorise #authorise [module]="properties.modules.project" [permission]="properties.permissions.CREATE">
  <ng-conatiner *ngIf="authorise.enable">
      <app-psm-list></app-psm-list>
  </ng-conatiner>
</app-authorise>
```

And condition is not required inside `app-authorise` again

app-authorise

```
<ng-container>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</ng-container>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/project-content-based-on-condition?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: works like a charm. Thank you Amit. Gotta change the code now :)

Answer (score 0):

Found this [custom-permission-directive](https://juristr.com/blog/2018/02/angular-permission-directive/) really helpfull.
One can use a directive instead of component.